# Problem about group_col in compare_df package in r

Tags: r

I have two dataframes with the same column name and I want to compare the two dataframe grouped by "investment Company" (one column name).

However, when I set the group_col to "Investment Company", it does not work. Only after I rename the column name "investment Company" to "IC", it works. I don't know why.

https://cran.r-project.org/package=compareDF

The code that doesn't work

```
library(compareDF)
```

```
compare_df(df1,df2, c("Investment Company"))
```

The code that works after rename the column name

```
compare_df(df1,df2, c("IC"))
```

Comment: Provide reproducible example.

Comment: This must be because of the following:
1. one of your two data-frames column is not actually called 'Investment Company' (Check for capitalization or spelling mistakes)
2. one of your two data-frames has multiple columns called 'Investment Company'.

Please produce a reproducible example for displaying a sample of your two data frames so that we can help you better.